# Sequelize + mySQL : How to delete item from a field that is an array

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a field in my model that I want to be an array, so I've defined it like this

```
names:{
            type : Sequelize.STRING,
            get(){
                return this.getDataValue('names')
            },
            set(value){
                return this.setDataValue('names', value)
            },
            default : []
        },}
```

Now i've found very little info on how to add an item to this array but I wrote this

```
    { where: { id: req.body.id } },
names: Sequelize.fn(
        "array_append",
        Sequelize.col("names"),
        userName
      )
    }
```

is this correct ?
what if I want to delete an item from this array ? what should be the contrary of array_append ?
Thanks for answering as the doc on the subject is very poor :)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays aren't really something that mySQL does. I see that you have defined the datatype as a STRING, which makes sense because there is no ARRAY datatype.

You can somewhat replicate the functionality of an array by turning the data into a comma-separated string, and potentially even wrapping that string in [] brackets, then doing some client-side Javascript with JSON.parse() or something along those lines, but that's A) A lot of work, and B) Makes it difficult to query for items inside the array.

The best way to approach this kind of functionality in most SQL dialects is to create a separate table with a relationship to the first table. So, for example, if you have a "Teams" table, and you want to store the Players that belong to the team, you would create a "Players" table which would include a teamId column relating each player to a team.

Your models would need association methods that would look something like

`Team.hasMany(Player)`

`Player.belongsTo(Team)`

If you are determined to use an array datatype in SQL, my understanding is that postgreSQL has support for them. Alternatively, you can use a noSQL database such as MongoDB.